# Latest VS code insiders right pannel

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have updated VS code insiders for the latest version.

[image]

Now it shows below kind of new panel right side of the editor.Can you tell me what is that and how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `setting.json` and set `"editor.minimap.enabled"` to `false`.

> The mini-map provides a summary of your code for a quick navigation.
>   It is a feature!
>
> the mini-map shows you the entire file/page you are working on. You
>   can quickly navigate it via the mini-map