# How to close vscode's miniature view?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

How to close the miniature view on the right side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latest VS code insiders right pannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246558/latest-vs-code-insiders-right-pannel)

Comment: Thanks. They are asking for the same answer. However, it has been a painful journey to find this answer. Without knowing the word 'minimap', it's hard to obtain the right page. ^^

Answer (score 5):

You are refering to the new minmap feature. Check [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_preview-minimap)

Set `"editor.minimap.enabled": false` in your user settings or workspace settings as per your requirements.